# openid connect integration in codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, single-sign-on, keycloak, openid-connect

I'm using keycloak for SSO. I have different apps where I successfully implement SSO including a SPA (Angular app) and Laravel APP. Now I want to implement in an App developed in CodeIgniter 3.

I'm using [jumbojett/OpenID-Connect-PHP](https://github.com/jumbojett/OpenID-Connect-PHP) Library to implement it in CI.
I created a custom Library `Keycloak.php` used in `Login` Controller.

**Library : Keycloak.php**

```
include_once APPPATH.'/third_party/OIDC/autoload.php';

use Jumbojett\OpenIDConnectClient;

class Keycloak {

    private $client;

    public function __construct() {
        $config = get_config()['keycloak'];
        $this->client = new OpenIDConnectClient(
            $config['keycloak_base_url'] ,
            $config['client_id'],
            $config['client_secret']
        );
        $this->client->setVerifyHost(false);
        $this->client->setVerifyPeer(false);
 

        $this->client->setRedirectURL(base_url('Login/callback'));
        $this->client->addScope($config['scopes']);

    }

   public function authenticate() {
       $this->client->authenticate();
   }

   public function handleCallback() {
       // check if access token already exists in session
       if(isset($_SESSION['access_token'])) {
          return $_SESSION['access_token'];
       }

       try {
           $code = $_GET['code'];
           $token = $this->client->authenticate($code);
           $token = $this->client->getAccessToken();
           $_SESSION['access_token'] = $token;
       }
       catch (\Exception $e) {
           echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
       }
       return $token;

   }

   public function getAccessToken() {
       return isset($_SESSION['access_token']) ? $_SESSION['access_token'] : null;
   }

   public function setAccessToken($accessToken) {
       $_SESSION['access_token'] = $accessToken;
   }

   public function verifyAccessToken() {
       $this->client->setAccessToken($this->getAccessToken());
       return $this->client->verifyJWT();
   }

   public function logout() {
       unset($_SESSION['access_token']);
   }

   public function getUserInfo() {
       try {
           $sub = $this->client->requestUserInfo();
       } catch (\Jumbojett\OpenIDConnectClientException $e) {
           echo $e;
       }
       return $sub;
   }
}
```

**LoginController.php**

```
class Login extends MX_Controller  {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('keycloak');
    }

    //Redirect user to keycloak login page.
    public function login() {
        $this->keycloak->authenticate();
    }

    //on successful authenticate keycloak server redirects to callback 
    public function callback() {
        $token = $this->keycloak->handleCallback();
        if($token) {
            $this->keycloak->setAccessToken($token);
            redirect('dashboard');
        } else {
            echo "Failed to authenticate with Keycloak.";
        }
    }

    public function logout() {
        $this->keycloak->logout();
        redirect('/login');
    }
```

When I visit the `login` route it redirect well to the Keycloak login page. After the login the infinite redirections occurs and my app die. Keycloak `client ID` and `client Secret` are both correct as well as the `redirect URL`.

My understanding is that `$this->keycloak->authenticate();` first initiates the login request. After successful login, Keycloak returns authorization code and then redirects to callback with code and state.

Here `$this->client->authenticate($code)` again authenticating authorization code and its failing and redirects to keycloak and keycloak redirect to local and an infinite loop here.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Screenshot of Too many redirection]